# llamar funcion desde Google map InfoWindows en ionic?

Tags: javascript, ionic, google-maps, api, typescript

Estoy tratado de llamar una funcion desde  un InfoWindows de Google Maps API, pero me muestra el siguiente error:

> (index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: ir is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)

Al parecer dice que la función `ir()` no está definida.

Éste es mi código:

```
addMarker(position,map,title){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position,
      map,
      title
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content:" "
    });

    marker.addListener('click',function(){
      infoWindow.setContent('<h1> '+ title +'</h1>' +
          '<button class="mapaboton" onclick="ir()">Ver Detalles</button>');

        infoWindow.open(map,marker);
    });

  }
```

Función `ir()`  la cual sí tengo definida:

```
  ir(){
    console.log("vamos");
  }
```

Al momento de darle click al botón que creo en el `infowindows` me muestra el error. Estuve investigando y no encuentro la respuesta.

Basicamente lo que trato de hacer es esto

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/8ZsSp/

Comment: Creo que le falta poner funcion al principio de la funcion.

Comment: no hace falta es typescript

Comment: Es un componente hecho en angular? Podemos ver la clase completa que define al componente?

Comment: edite la pregunta y eh dejado todo el codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente encontré la solución

básicamente es  colocarle un id al botton

```html
   marker.addListener('click',function(){
      infoWindow.setContent('<h1> '+ title +'</h1>' +
          '<button id="' + id +'"  class="mapaboton" >Ver Detalles</button>'); 
        infoWindow.open(map,this);
    });
```

y luego

un evento addListenerOnce

```html
   google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infoWindow, 'domready', () => {
      document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', () => {
               this.navCtrl.push(RestauranteDetallePage,{ codigo : id})
          });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que ir() no es una función, es un método de tu componente, por eso no escribiste `function` delante (no es por que sea [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tiene la misma sintaxis):

```js
class MiClase {

  constructor() {
    this.atributo="hola";
  }
  
  ir() {
    console.log(this.atributo);
  }
  
  addOnClick() {
  console.log('add');  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML='<label onclick="ir()">hola</label>';
  }
}

let obj= new MiClase();

obj.ir();
obj.addOnClick();
```

```css
#test {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Por tanto, tienes que definir la función fuera del componente para que sea accesible:

```js
class MiClase {

  constructor() {
    this.atributo="hola";
  }
  
  ir() {
    console.log(this.atributo);
  }
  
  addOnClick() {
  console.log('add');  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML='<label onclick="ir()">hola</label>';
  }
}



let obj= new MiClase();
let ir= obj.ir.bind(obj);
obj.addOnClick();
```

```css
#test {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```